# Predict the output of the C code

Tags: c, stack

I attended an interview where this code was written and I had to predict the output of the code.

```
int foo() {
  int a;
  a = 5;
  return a;
}

void main() {
  int b;
  b = foo();
  printf ("The returned value is %d\n", b);
}
```

The answer was so obvious to me and I answered 5. But the interviewer said the answer is unpredictable since the function would have been popped from the stack after return. Could anyone kindly clarify me on this?

Comment: This is `C`, so use `int main` instead of `void main`.

Comment: If I was in your place, and got selected, I would still not take the job to a company that does not know the difference between `void main` and `int main`, and where to put what.

Comment: Either you or the interviewer has omitted something critical, like indirection.  Are you *sure* that it wasn't declared as `int * foo() { int a = 5; return &a; }` ?  If that's the case, then the interviewer was correct.  If not, the interviewer failed to transcribe the test correctly because that was likely the goal.

Comment: Are you reproducing the code from memory? Are you sure the code was exactly as you have shown? My guess would be that the actual code shown to you had `foo` returning a pointer to a local variable which is then dereferenced in `main`. In which case the answer given would make sense (though it's worded somewhat wrong - again possibly due to your rephrasing).

Comment: `the function would have been popped from the stack after return` If your interviewer did in fact say anything remotely like that, then be happy you won't work there. If on the other hand the question maybe was about `char *foo()` with a local `char a[123];` then that's a whole different story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code as you have presented it does not have the problem the interviewer asserted it does.  This code would:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * foo ( void ) {
    int a = 5;               /* as a local, a is allocated on "the stack" */
    return &a;               /* and will not be "alive" after foo exits */
}                            /* so this is "undefined behavior" */

int main ( void ) {
    int b = *foo();          /* chances are "it will work", or seem to */
    printf("b = %d\n", b);   /* as we don't do anything which is likely */
    return 0;                /* to disturb the stack where it lies in repose */
}                            /* but as "UB" anything can happen */
```

Comment: Surprisingly my compiler always throw me an warning if I am trying to return the address of a local variable